# angular routing to previous component doesnt work

Tags: angular, routes

I try to call the back arrow from the browser to detect when the user clicks the button. This works well but i want to go to a certain component when it has clicked. To do so i have created this.

```js
export class BlogdetailComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private sub: any;
  id: string;
  title: string;
  body: String;
  imageUrl: String;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router,
    private _location: Location, location: PlatformLocation) {
    location.onPopState(() => {
      console.log('back clicked')
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/welcome');
    });
  }

  backClicked() {
    this._location.back();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      const blogtitle = params['blogtitle'];
      const blogbody = params['blogbody'];
      const image = params['imageUrl'];
      console.log('hure', image);
      this.imageUrl = image;
      this.title = blogtitle;
      this.body = blogbody;
    });
  }
}
```

The problem is that it stays at the same component and receive only different parameter from the previous component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest changing the code to use the `CanDeactivate`  guard instead of checking the back button.

You can check the info of the guards here: https://angular.io/guide/router

If you still want to use the pop, Angular says that you **shouldn't** use the `PlatformLocation`, and use the `Location` instead.
( https://angular.io/api/common/PlatformLocation )

To use the location you can do something like this:

```
import { SubscriptionLike } from 'rxjs';

private subscription: SubscriptionLike;

 constructor(location: Location) {

    this.subscription = location.subscribe(() => {
      setTimeout(() => this.router.navigateByUrl('/welcome'), 20);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

You need a setTimeout because of the angular app life. Note that you are going to have a navigation to the previous url too. If you want to skip that you can use : `this.router.navigateByUrl('/welcome', {replaceUrl:true})`

**Live example here:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stack-55698013-routingonpop?file=src/app/hello.component.ts